# Spring request params custom parsing

Tags: java, spring, parameters

My request params look like this ?filter=price:120-130&filter=brand:samsung&filter=brand:sony

the params parsed by spring are filter[] ->

1. price:120-130,
2. brand:samsung,
3. brand:sony

However, it barfs if my params have comma in it.For eg:?filter=price:12,00-13,00&filter=brand:samsung&filter=brand:sony

the params parsed are filter[] ->

1. price:12,
2. 00-13,
3. 00,
4. brand:samsung,
5. brand:sony

where as expect my params to be

1. price:12,00-13,00
2. brand:samsung
3. brand:sony

How do i make spring not parse comma as separator for an individual request parameters.

Comment: Check the next URL works for me:

   [How to create or build Filters in Spring Framework][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328605/how-to-create-or-build-filters-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to decode a request string from a URL? If so, you can try to HTML encode the characters that are giving you a problem. Google HTML and URL encoding for more info.